# GitHub Actions powershell shell not working pwsh: command not found

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions, powershell-core

I have a github actions runner running on my win10 machine, it is running in command prompt. I have a basic github actions workflow here:

```
name: Release New NuGet Package Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      nugetPkgProjectName:
        description: 'Enter your NuGet Package Project Name:'
        required: true
        type: string
      incrementMinorVersion:
          description: 'Set to "true" if you want to increment minor and set patch to zero.'
          required: false
          type: string
      descriptionVar:
          description: 'What changes were made in this version?'
          required: false
          type: string

jobs:
  begin:
    runs-on: martin-laptop
    steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            sparse-checkout: |
              Martin Nuget Work

        - name: Extract Branch and Commit
          run: |
            echo "Branch = ${{ github.ref_name }}"
            echo "Commit = ${{ github.sha }}"

        - name: Determine NuGet Package Version
          id: run-ps-script
          shell: pwsh
          run: |
            Write-Host "here is some pwsh stuff"
            Write-Host "cool env var : $env:GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/Martin Nuget Work"
```

When I trigger this workflow in github actions, it fails at the last step 'Determine NuGet Package Version' with this error:

```
  Run Write-Host "here is some pwsh stuff"
  Write-Host "here is some pwsh stuff"
  Write-Host "cool env var : $env:GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/Martin Nuget Work"
  Error: pwsh: command not found
```

This has worked fine in the past, but now on this new machine, a pwsh shell command never passes, is it an issue with my runner?

Comment: Have you verified that `martin-laptop` has PowerShell installed and that the installation path is in the `%PATH%` env variable of the process hosting the runner? Next obvious step would be to [inspect the log files](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-self-hosted-runners#reviewing-the-self-hosted-runner-application-log-files)

Comment: Fixed by replacing pwsh with powershell

Comment: That's not called "fixed". `pwsh` (release 6 and above) and `powershell` (release 5.1) are indeed different things, and you should install the latest PowerShell release from Microsoft to make `pwsh` available on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `martin-laptop` has `pwsh` installed (can you type `pwsh` locally from your command line)
2. Set the shell that the command is executing in to be `pwsh` either through defaults or on your specific step.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun

Ex:

```yaml
name: Sample Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: pwsh

    steps:
      - name: Run a script with pwsh in a specific step
        shell: pwsh
        run: Write-Host "This step specifically uses pwsh as its shell."
```